Concatenating custom strings works, but unstably
I want to build concatenated strings in AHK v. 1.1 from seperate strings that I select consecutively with my mouse by pressing (down) Caps lock + y each time.
When I'm done selecting all text snippets, I want to place the so concatenated string into the clipboard and reset MyGlobal to nothing, all upon releasing Caps lock.
Most of the time, the following code accomplishes that task just fine:
SetCapsLockState AlwaysOff 

MyGlobal := ""

~CapsLock & y::
    Sleep 100
    Send ^c
    ClipWait, 15
    MyGlobal := MyGlobal . Trim(clipboard) . " " 
    clipboard := ""   
Return

CapsLock up::
    KeyWait, CapsLock 
    
    if(MyGlobal <>""){
    MyGlobal := Trim(MyGlobal)  
    clipboard := MyGlobal
    MyGlobal := ""                       
}
Return

However, still too often, the above code messes up my string, e.g. by preceding the next combined string with the last part of the last combined string (which should by then already have been deleted by MyGlobal := "").
Can you help me make my code more robust?

(I understand that you are on AHK v1.1, but the following solution is in V2. I have migrated all my script to V2 and haved forgotten the AHK V1.1 syntax, but you could translate back to the V1.1 variant quite easily I presume; I would strongly suggest migrating to V2 for its consistent syntax and continued support)
This worked reliably from my own testing, with the advantage of being in a single managable code block, and not using global variables at all.
It works by:

Manually ensuring that one instance of the hotkey function is running at a time using a simple function scoped static boolean (isRunning);
Manually handling repeated "Y" presses and "capslock lift up" using a while loop.

#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

CapsLock & Y::{
    static isRunning := 0
    if (isRunning) {
        return
    }
    isRunning := 1

    concatenatedString := ""
    while (GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P")) {
        if (GetKeyState("Y", "P")) {
            A_Clipboard := ""
            Send "^c"
            ClipWait 100, 1
            concatenatedString := concatenatedString . Trim(A_Clipboard) . " " 
            KeyWait "Y"
        }
    }
    
    if(concatenatedString != ""){
        A_Clipboard := Trim(concatenatedString)  
    }
    
    isRunning := 0
}


Thanks. The static variable seems to be unable to be declared at that line in v 1.1 and the clipboard needs to be emptied after sending ^c. Otherwise your script looks good and I'm giving it a spin to test it for reliability. In the meantime I upvoted your answer ;-)

Hmm I suspect that the ClipWait related issue you encountered could be a bug; the whole point of ClipWait is to block the thread until clipboard contains data

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/ClipWait.htm

The example call sequence for "copy attempts" on both V1 and V2 is the same: 1. Clear clipboard, 2. Send Ctrl C, 3. Clip wait

Ok, I tested your script and unfortunately it's no more stable in practise than mine. I'll keep your answer upvoted though, but don't "accept" it, still hoping for some other miraculous answer...

Now you got me interested, I have no clue what could have went wrong... Perhaps try posting on AHK forums they have great people there

This may be what you want.
SetCapsLockState AlwaysOff 

MyVar := "" ;   it's not a GLOBAL, it's just a var

~CapsLock & y::
    clipboard := "" ;   If you don't clear the clipboard, the LAST sequence will still be stored in it after the first run (when Caps Lock is released).
    Sleep 100
    Send ^c
    ClipWait, 15
    MyVar := (MyVar ? MyVar " " :  MyVar) . Trim(clipboard)
Return

CapsLock up::
    KeyWait, CapsLock 

    if  MyVar    {
        temp_clipboard := MyVar ;   stores the sequence in a temp clipboard
        MyVar := ""
    }
Return

^v::    ;   paste the sequence saved
    SendInput,% temp_clipboard
Return


Not exactly, but thanks nevertheless.
